# My multidimensional list is executing 'np.array'.It report an error

Tags: numpy-ndarray

Display error:setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (20, 15) + inhomogeneous part.

I want to try to make the list multidimensional a uniformlength,or some other way to solve the error